# how to get the row in the table which is having the null value and also didnt no about any column name?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table as below

```
create table col(id int,name varchar(max))
insert into col values(1,'n1'),(2,'n2'),(3,'n3'),(4,null)
```

I need the output of the 4th row which is having the null value. But I don't know the column name in the table, I only know about the table name.

can you please help to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the NULL valued records from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660282/how-can-i-get-the-null-valued-records-from-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird case. Why do you need to do this at all? But anyway, you can obtain the names of the columns from `sys.syscolumns` table and construct a dynamic query where to check each column is it null or not, like this:

```
select * from col where 1=2 or id is null or name is null
```

The whole query could be as follows:

```
create table col(id int,name varchar(max))
insert into col values(1,'n1'),(2,'n2'),(3,'n3'),(4,null)

declare @TableName sysname = N'col'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select * from ' + @TableName + ' where 1=2';

select @sql += ' or ' + name + ' is null'
from sys.syscolumns
where id = object_id(@TableName) and isnullable = 1

-- print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```